# How to implement JSAPI as voice changer in android application

Tags: java, android, audio

How to implement JSAPI as voice changer in android with sample project so that i can use it for voice changer app

```
               int i = 0;
                while(dataInputStream.available() > 0){
                    audioData[i] = dataInputStream.readShort();
                    i++;
                }

                dataInputStream.close();

                int sampleFreq = (Integer)spFrequency.getSelectedItem();

                AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(
                        AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                        sampleFreq,
                        AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                        bufferSizeInBytes,
                        AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
```

I am new to android, i would really appreciate any help

Comment: some one plzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz

Comment: how to add effect to the audio